# Visual studio web performance test, javascript

Tags: javascript, web-testing

I am recording web performance test on web page, and I need to count time since I click on button until the next wanted page is rendered.
The problem is that I have a lot of client side logic that is triggered on the button click.
So, some time is past while javascript is executing and after that request is being sent to server.

web performance test records only web request between client and server, javascript time is never recorded.

I need to record actual time since I click to button to next page opening(including javascript time)

Can that be done in Visual Studio Web performance?
If not, is there some alternative?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik's Test Studio's new performance test feature measures client side processing time.   We break out server-side and client-side times. Client times are based on a particular test step's total execution time less the server time for that step.

As long as the next step in the test has the output of the current test's JavaScript as a prerequisite then that step's client time will include time needed for the JavaScript to finish its work. This would generally be the case unless the next step is a direct navigation step.

(Disclosure: I work for Telerik as their Test Studio evangelist.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between measuring server side performance during high load scenarios and the rendering time for the client. Especially as client side rendering is going to depend a lot on the browser version.

If you want to do heavy load testing, I would recommend doing the load testing with Visual Studio to determine how quickly the server processes the http requests. It is important to isolate client rendering from your functional and client side performance testing.

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), [HTTPWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) are browser plugins that allow you to analyze a client view of individual page performance.

The Telerik Test Studio looks like a comprehensive suite, but I have not used it... fortunately they do have a trial version.

Comment: HttpWatch and Firebug are just looking http request and responses I do not see javascript measurement, am I missing something?